# Default case in toString for enums

Tags: java, enums, tostring

I am somewhat new to enums in Java, and I am trying to override toString() so that it can return special cases for an enum with creating code for each case:

```
enum TestEnum {
One, Two, Three,
Exclamation, Ampersand, Asterisk;

public String toString() {
    if (this == Ampersand) return "&";
    if (this == Exclamation) return "!";
    if (this == Asterisk) return "*";
    return null; // return toString(); ???
}
```

If I use toString as the default return statement, I obviously get a StackOverflowError. Is there a way to get around this and return any cases not included in the toString()?

Comment: your concern is unclear, why do you think you will get  a  `StackOverflowError` ?

Comment: @SergeyPauk: Because `return toString();` would just call the same method recursively.

Comment: ok, now I got what is author trying to achieve, answer upvoted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to get around this and return any cases not included in the toString()?

I think you just want:

```
return super.toString();
```

Then it won't call itself - it'll just use the superclass implementation.

However, I'd change the implementation to make the string representation a field within the enum value, specified at construction time where necessary:

```
enum TestEnum {
    One, Two, Three,
    Exclamation("!"), Ampersand("&"), Asterisk("*");

    private final String name;

    private TestEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private TestEnum() {
        name = super.toString();
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Tested with:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        for (TestEnum x : TestEnum.values()) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
One
Two
Three
!
&
*
```